# Can you keep a gui application running with ssh x11 forwarding after closing the ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

There is an electron app I want to run in a remote machine, and it works through an ssh -X connection.

The thing is that I would like that application to continue running even after I close the connection, and be able to resume it's execution at a later point. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Xpra](https://xpra.org/).

> On X11, it is also known as screen for X11: it allows you to run
> programs, usually on a remote host, direct their display to your local
> machine, and then to **disconnect from these programs and reconnect** from
> the same or another machine, without losing any state.